# Haskell parse error in my xmonad.hs config that i don't understand?

Tags: linux, haskell, window-managers, xmonad

So i downloaded a xmonad wm config off of github that I thought looked nice, tried to use it and I got a parse error. I don't have too much Haskell knowledge but nothing looks wrong?

```
xmonad.hs:72:13: parse error on input ‘]’
```

Area in question:

```
addedKeys = [ ("M-<Return>"  , spawn myTerm),
          ("M-e"         , spawn "gedit"),
          ("M-i"         , spawn "firefox"),
          ("M-S-t"       , spawn "nemo"),
          ("M-<Left>"    , windows W.swapMaster >> windows W.focusDown),
        ]
```

Comment: Indentation matters in Haskell. Make sure the everything is indented at least as much as the equals sign.

Comment: @SebastianRedl It was just an extra comma, indentation was fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
addedKeys = [ ("M-<Return>"  , spawn myTerm),
              ("M-e"         , spawn "gedit"),
              ("M-i"         , spawn "firefox"),
              ("M-S-t"       , spawn "nemo"),
              ("M-<Left>"    , windows W.swapMaster >> windows W.focusDown)]
```

There was a comma after the last item in the list which caused the error.